# Replace a string from python df issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to separate few string from  pandas dataframe :

```
x = pd.DataFrame()
x['y'] = ["Hernia|Infiltration","A|Hernia|Infiltration","Infiltration|Hernia"]
x
```

I am executing below code :

```
x['y'] = x['y'].replace({'|Hernia': ''},regex=True)
x['y'] = x['y'].str.replace('Hernia|', '',regex=True)
x
```

But output is wrong :

wrong output :

```
     y
0   |Infiltration
1   A||Infiltration
2   Infiltration|
```

Correct/ Expected output

```
     y
0   Infiltration
1   A|Infiltration
2   Infiltration
```

There can be any string in place of A and Infiltration , but pattern would be same.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `regex=True` when you're trying to replace a literal string rather than a regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape `|` in `replace`:

```
x['y'] = x['y'].replace({'\|Hernia': ''},regex=True)
x['y'] = x['y'].replace({'Hernia\|': ''},regex=True)
```

Taking from @user3483203 and @piRSquared's comments, you can join them with `|` acting as an `or`:

```
x['y'].replace({'\|Hernia|Hernia\|': '',
                '':''},regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Since `.replace()` takes a dictionary, you can put both keys in the same dict.

Comment: But you can separate them with a `'|'`... `x['y'].replace({'\|Hernia|Hernia\|': ''},regex=True)`

Answer (score 3):

This can probably be more elegantly handled with split/join

```
x['y'].apply(lambda row: '|'.join(x for x in row.split('|') if 'Hernia'!= x))
```

Output:

```
0      Infiltration
1    A|Infiltration
2      Infiltration
```

Comment: It should be `if 'Hernia' != x` Otherwise, you'll remove `Herniated disk` as well.

Comment: You can use a comprehension instead of `apply`... `['|'.join(filter('Hernia'.__ne__, s.split('|'))) for s in x.y]`